# Postgres Analysis with respect to parameters

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to check the following parameters wrt postgres:

Memory utilization
CPU utilization
Disk space
Number of DB locks

What command should i use to check each of them.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

after login using psql you may run the following commands to get information related to Memory utilization.

```
show shared_buffers;
show temp_buffers;
show maintenance_work_mem;
```

More details can be found at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-resource.html

and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-connection.html